# Run ELK with filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, wsl-2

I try to start ELK in docker-compose in WSL2. But I can't find any indexes in kibana.
[Test code.](https://github.com/klynxe/ELK)
I try to load any logs from `/var/log/*.log` using `filebeat`

When I open kibana `http://localhost:5601/` it offer to add new data.

I expected data in kibana on indexes witch must be created by beanfile.